# Javascript image panel with images the same size

Tags: javascript, image

What is the best way to display a panel of different sized images as all being the same size. Is there a simple Javascript framework that can handle the resizing and possibly some cropping.

For example if you look at Pinterest you will see that all the images have variable sizes (we can use jQuery masonry for this). But then when you look at this page, http://pinterest.com/pin/97249673174024268/ all the images are the same size.

Firstly is my question sensible and secondly is there a way we can achieve this with a Javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this entirely in JavaScript, it's simple enough that you don't need a library. If you have jQuery, it makes it even easier.

1. Place the image inside a `<div>` with the width and height set to your desired size, 'overflow' set to 'hidden', and 'position' is either 'absolute' or 'relative'.
2. Get the size of the image:

   ```
   var imageWidth = $(image).width(),
       imageHeight = $(image).height();
   ```

   (If it was loaded into a JavaScript Image object, you can also just get it from `image.width` and `image.height`)
3. Do a bit of math figure out how much to shrink or enlarge it:

   ```
   var widthScale = divWidth/imageWidth, 
       heightScale = divHeight/imageHeight,
       scale = Math.max(widthScale, heightScale),
       newWidth = Math.round(imageWidth*scale),
       newHeight = Math.round(imageHeight*scale);
   ```

   Essentially,this figures out how much it would need scale the image to make the width fit and to make the height fit, then picks the larger of the two so the image fits on one side and overflows on the other.
4. Style the image to fit the new size and center it inside the div:

   ```
   $(image).css({
       width: newWidth+'px', 
       height: newHeight+'px', 
       position: 'absolute',
       left: '50%', 
       top: '50%', 
       margin-left: 0-Math.round(newWidth/2)+'px',
       margin-top:  0-Math.round(newHeight/2)+'px'
   });
   ```

That should do it!

Answer (score 1):

This plugin [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tiles-gallery/2281417) can handle varying image sizes and arrange them like you want.